# Cannot get Sequelize validation working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement validation in my Sequelize models. The model is defined as follows

```
var model = sequelize.define('Model', {
  from: {
    type:               DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull:          false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
}
```

Then I'm trying to build an instance and validate it:

```
var m = Model.build({ from: 'obviously not a email' });
var err = m.validate();
```

But if I do `console.log(err)`, I get `{ fct: [Function] }` only. Defining a custom validator that throws an exception results in an unhandled exception.

How should I use `validate()` properly?

Comment: @sdepold First I've tried 2.0.0-alpha2. I've managed to understand that it uses promises instead of direct return value, just this is not described in the documentation yet. Now I've rolled back to 1.6.0 where value is returned directly. I'll try to work it out with promises later

Comment: Interested in a 2.0.0-solution?

Comment: @sdepold it would be nice, thanks

Comment: will provide one later the day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how to get your problem solved with Sequelize `v2.0.0`:

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize")
  , sequelize = new Sequelize("sequelize_test", "root")

var Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
  from: {
    type:      Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate:  {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
})

Model.sync().success(function() {
  Model.build({ from: "foo@bar" }).validate().success(function(errors) {
    console.log(errors)
  })
})
```

This will result in:

```
{ from: [ 'Invalid email' ] }
```

Side note: You can also skip the `validate`-call and just create the instance instead:

```
Model.sync().success(function() {
  Model
    .create({ from: "foo@bar" })
    .success(function() {
      console.log('ok')
    })
    .error(function(errors) {
      console.log(errors)
    })
})
```

The error method will receive the very same error object as in the previous code snippet.

Greetings,
sdepold.

Comment: They really need to update the documentation to indicate that validation is no longer synchronous. The result of validate() is definitely some sort of promise object, but the documentation leaves this out completely. :(

Comment: True. Will try to do this later the day.

Comment: I think it's important to note explicitly that when `validate()` fails, it still calls `success()`, but with a list of errors. Easy to assume `error()` would be called on a failed validation.

Comment: The docs are in need of a major update. I keep getting the promise notices since bluebird/promise has changed where they are expecting .then .catch etc. not what is shown above. This is very confusing for most who are trying to use sequelize. I'm unable to get the validation to work. It continues to insert a string that should be a isURL however missing the http protocols.

Comment: I just tried with the isInt: true validator and it got into the catch so it's the isUrl that is failing. Removed the .com at the end and the url validator doesn't care about the protocol in the beginning yet the docs mention "// checks for url format (http://foo.com)". I'll submit an issue on github.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach for validating in Sequelize, use a hook instead of a model validation. I'm using the 'beforeValidate' hook and adding custom validation (using validator module) with Promises that are rejected when validation fails.

```
var validator = require('validator');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    email: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });
  //validate here
  User.hook('beforeValidate', function(user, options) {
    if(validator.isEmail(user.email)){
      return sequelize.Promise.resolve(user);
    }else{
      return sequelize.Promise.reject('Validation Error: invalid email');
    }
 });
 return User;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me
In model use :-

```
var model = sequelize.define('Model', {
  from: {
    type:               DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull:          false,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  }
}
```

In your control logic while you save model do this :-

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var Model = require('your_model_folderpath').model;

Model.create({from: 'not email'}).then(function(model) {
                    // if validation passes you will get saved model
            }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function(err) {
                    // responds with validation errors
            }).catch(function(err) {
                    // every other error
            });
```